# Some columns in a DataGridView is readonly

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Is it possible that only selected columns in a datagridview is readonly?
If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this sample;

```
dataGridView1.Columns["CompanyName"].ReadOnly = true;
```

Re: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cze614bb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Hope this will help. Regards,